# Which planet resembles Hoth?

Tags: star-wars, astronomy

Which planet or moons in our solar system resembles the Hoth planet from *Star Wars*?

Comment: No other planets or heavenly bodies in our solar system have solid water as depicted in Star Wars with tolerable temperatures or atmosphere. A moon of Saturn called "Titan" is known to be convered a thick crust of frozen liquid however. This ice is exposed to the vacuum of space and is rocked by earthquakes, geysers, and rapid sublimation however. It's actually an awesome place.

Comment: The 'Titan' has the earth kind of topography but all that titan has is methane.Methane rivers,methane rains,methane seas,Methane falls.But hoth is icy,more like a ice desert.I am looking for a planet close to icy hoth

Comment: Check the planets of jupiter moons Europa,lo,ganymede and dwarf planet Pluto.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Pluto

According to [Space.com](http://www.space.com/12961-10-real-alien-worlds-star-wars-planets.html):

> Hoth, the snow-covered planet featured during the AT-AT battle at the beginning of "Star Wars Episode V: The Empire Strikes Back," bears a resemblance to planet OGLE-2006-BLG-390. With a surface temperature of -364 degrees Fahrenheit (-220 degrees Celsius), it is nearly as frigid as Pluto.

Now planet OGLE-2006-BLG-390 (already mentioned by @NicolaBastianello in her answer) isn't in our solar system, but Pluto is. OK, according to the IAU, Pluto is [no longer a planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluto#IAU_classification), but dwarf planets still count in my book! Among the nine (including Pluto) planets in our solar system:

- Jupiter and Saturn are [**gas giants**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_giant), much hotter and more gaseous than the terrestrial planet Hoth
- Uranus and Neptune are [**ice giants**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_giant), which are colder then gas giants and composed of heavier elements, but are still not terrestrial planets
- Mercury, Venus, Earth, and Mars are terrestrial planets, close to the sun and much warmer than Hoth

Which leaves Pluto: cold, icy, and inhospitable.

Hoth is an [ice planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planets_in_science_fiction#Ice_planets), and [ice planets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_planet) in our solar system include "the icy moons Europa, Enceladus, and Triton and the dwarf planets Pluto and Eris". Eris, of a roughly similar size to Pluto, is also a candidate; its surface, like Pluto's, contains methane ice. But Hoth has six moons, which is closer to Pluto's four than Eris's one. So our final candidate must be **Pluto**.

Comment: Also if we talk about atmosphere,Recent data from new horizons,pluto has atmosphere thick enough to have a mild winds and also has a rich landscape.I think if we see in that aspect pluto can be our final dwarf planet resembling hoth.

Comment: Sorry guys, but you speak like not having sense of scale. Hoth is like Mars with atmosphere taken from Earth. Incomparable with Pluto.

Comment: Europa would be a better choice than Pluto. It is significantly larger, has more gravity, and a lot more sunlight to see by.

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic of planet Hoth have been reviewed to find a resemblance to real planets [here](http://www.space.com/12961-10-real-alien-worlds-star-wars-planets.html), with the following result:

> Hoth [...] bears a resemblance to planet OGLE-2006-BLG-390.

But OGLE-2006-BLG-390 is not a planet in our solar system. [Here](http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2005/06/photogalleries/starwarsgalaxy/photo5.html), instead, you can find a quote by a scientist at the Planetary Society in Pasadena, which concludes that the existence of a planet like Hoth is infeasible:

> "A nearby asteroid field? Hmm, it would be tricky to keep it in place." [...] "Perhaps it's early in that solar system's development and the planet, like early Earth, is under bombardment. But then it would be odd to have very advanced life evolved there."

Comment: Earth in its ice age might have been like hoth. But i was kind of referring to the topology rather than its support for life.So what can be a near topologically similar

Comment: @r2_d2 What do you mean by topology? Topologically Hoth is homeomorphic to a ball and therefore homotopic to a point, just like any other known planet.

Comment: @randal'thor I was referring to the terrestrial features(topography).